# How to set description in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm a new [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) user.

The examples I have found on-line and the Wiki [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/General-Chart-Settings-&-Styling) all give the setDescription() prototype as:

```
setDescription(String desc)`
```

However, `mChart.setDescription("");` does not compile for me and AndroidStudio->Go To Declaration tells me the declaration for setDescription defined in Chart.java is :

```
   public void setDescription(Description desc) {
        this.mDescription = desc;
    }
```

And the Description constructor in Description.java does not take a String.

How do I set the description (or at least turn it off)?  Am I pointing to the wrong libraries?

Here is my app's gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And, the module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.nbmc_hbmc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And this is my chart code.  It compiles and shows the chart but it has the Description Label "Description Label" that I can't change or turn off.

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Description;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.android.nbmc_hbmc.R.id.chart;

public class NbmcEcgGraphActivity extends Activity {


    private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    private LineChart mChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ecggraph);
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_ecggraph);

        // Create new line chart
        LineChart mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(chart);

        mChart.setDescription(new Description());
        mChart.setNoDataText("No Data Yet");
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like the wiki is out of date!

The correct syntax in `MPAndroidChart` 3.0.1 is

```
mChart.getDescription().setText("Description of my chart");
```

Reference: [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.html#getDescription--)

Comment: Thanks -- your solution works.  (I'd +1 if I could).

Comment: Cheers, this helped me.Don't forget to close the quote on that string.

Comment: This doesn't work for me`PieChart pieChart = findViewById(R.id.piechart);
        pieChart.getDescription().setText("Description of my chart");`
 it gives the error *cant resolve method getDescription()*