# MPAndroidChart v3.x.x: upgraded from 2.x.x labels

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

As mentioned in the title, I am working on a project where MPAndroidChart version 2.2.3 is used. In this project, Bar chart is currently used.

I am doing the version upgraded to 3.0.1. After the upgrade, few things below does not work anymore:

1.

```
mBarChart.setDescription("");
```

2.

```
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(1);
```

3.

```
BarData barData = new BarData(ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<IBarDataSet>);
```

I looked around but seems like there is no explanation for those issue, even in the release note.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## First question

> `mBarChart.setDescription();` doesn't work anymore

As per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41782984/5241933) the correct way to set description is now:

```
    mChart.getDescription().setText("Description of my chart);
```

## Third question

> `BarData barData = new BarData(ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<IBarDataSet>);` doesn't work anymore

There is a different method of adding labels than before. In MPAndroidChart 2.x.x you would pass the xIndex labels as an `ArrayList<String>` parameter for the constructor of `BarData`. If you try that in 3.x.x then you will get a message like this:

```
BarData (com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet...) in BarData cannot be applied to (java.lang.String[],java.util.ArrayList<com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet>)
```

This applies to many popular but outdated tutorials like the [Truition tutorial for MPAndroidChart here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-chart-example-mp-android-chart-library/)

Instead, in MPAndroidChart 3.x.x the way to do this is by using a `IAxisValueFormatter`. This interface has a single method `getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis)` which you implement to programatically generate your label.

There is an example in the [sample project](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/custom/MyAxisValueFormatter.java) and in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860000/5241933)

Altogether, the correct way to add data to a BarChart in MPAndroidChart3.x.x is the following (as per the example in the sample project):

```
 ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
 dataSets.add(set1);
 BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
 mChart.setData(data);
 mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new MyCustomValueFormatter()); // your own class that implements IAxisValueFormatter
```

Note: if you *must* use an `ArrayList<String>` for your labels you can use the convenience class [IndexAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/IndexAxisValueFormatter.java)

You consume it like this:

```
List<String> labels;
//TODO: code to generate labels, then
mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));
```

You will need:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1);
mChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

to mimic the behaviour of MPAndroidChart 2.x.x where only whole number xIndices receive labels.

As for your **second question**, because the label functionality is very finely controlled by the `IAxisValueFormatter` you won't need the `setSpaceBetweenLabels()` any more.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. So in this case, where will the ArrayList<IBarDataSet> be? Should I also manually set it in the YAxis? How can I do it? Thanks. Btw, Question 1 and 2 has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is as per the sample project : `ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>(); dataSets.add(set1); BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);`

Comment: It works for me know. I see. So now we can no longer set the ArrayList<String> to the constructor anymore but have to do it separately in the setValueFormatter. Thanks a lot. You save me few days ;)