# MPAndroidChart - axis labels and screen display

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am trying to implement a simple bar chart with MPAndroidChart and this tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335

I could get the chart on the screen but I have two questions:
1- I could not add the axis labels. The tutorial says:

```
BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
```

However I think they updated the library and now labels is not a parameter of the constructor anymore - it just accepts the dataset. In this case I tried to find but could not - how do I set the labels now?

2- The example displays in the entire screen. Say I would like to have a defined view space in my screen for the chart, how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this for your first question [MPAndroidChart v3.x.x: upgraded from 2.x.x labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818963/mpandroidchart-v3-x-x-upgraded-from-2-x-x-labels)